# Plesk 9.2.1 and Failure Notices

Tags: centos, email

I am helping my sister's church by hosting their site and email on a virtual server (CentOS 5). I use Plesk 9.2.1 and have attempted to beat back Failure Notices, hundreds of Failure Notices every day. Their computers are protected with NOD32 and the pastor said they ran scans on all workstations.

But the Failure Notices continue. Adjusting SpamAssassin hasn't worked.

Any suggestions on how to fix the problem, or at least track down the source?

Comment: By failure notices, are you referring to e-mail bounces?  Have you looked at the headers to see if they're coming from your server or other locations?  Perhaps someone is using your e-mail server to send spam?  May also be backscatter from someone spamming using their domain name, in which case an SPF record may help (likely not much, but maybe).

Comment: Failure notices are coming from server.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you/your sister's church is suffering from is a [Joe Job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_job)
SenderID/SPF records can help in this case but it is not a complete solution.
I have SPF records published for my domain and 2 weeks ago I awoke to about 40 of these 'bounce messages'. That was it though. It stopped at that.
I suspect the *spammers* got far to many notifications from servers honouring my SPF records and it caused them problems so they removed my domain from their *fake this domain* list.

**UPDATE**:  P.S. Trying to find the culprit/source of the *bounce messages* will prove to be quite a sizeable challenge if not near impossible.
This starts with emails being sent out from *botnets* with your domain in the From: header and poorly configured mail servers bouncing the mail to the address in the From: header.